# nodemon install problem as development mode

Tags: node.js

Whenever I try to install nodemon as dev-dependency, It gives me some errors, I do not know what to do. I tried `npm install nodemon --save-dev` but it gives me the same errors

I disabled virus protection, run cmd as administrator, but the same problem again

```
PS D:\My documents\My programs\akademind\nodejs-complete-guide> npm install nodemon --save-dev
npm WARN nodejs-complete-guide@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'D:\My documents\My programs\akademind\nodejs-complete-guide\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-c44863db\node_modules\abbrev' -> 'D:\My documents\My programs\akademind\nodejs-complete-guide\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-fa5cb67d'
```

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path D:\My documents\My programs\akademind\nodejs-complete-guide\node_modules\expand-brackets\node_modules\debug
npm ERR! dest D:\My documents\My programs\akademind\nodejs-complete-guide\node_modules\undefsafe\node_modules\debug
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\My documents\My programs\akademind\nodejs-complete-guide\node_modules\expand-brackets\node_modules\debug' -> 'D:\My documents\My programs\akademind\nodejs-complete-guide\node_modules\undefsafe\node_modules\debug'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!

    C:\Users\Farrux\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-15T13_53_36_783Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform the following steps:

- Delete `package-lock.json` file
- Delete `node_modules` folder  and
- Install packages by running `npm i`.

Comment: Ok. Let try:   1. npm cache clean -f
                     2. rm -rf node_modules
                     3. npm i

Comment: It is saying => Remove-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'rf'.
At line:1 char:4
+ rm -rf node_modules
+    ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: Ok. So just delete this folder in any other way.